# If / Else working just after reload page

Tags: jquery

### IF / ELSE - jQuery

I have a code, but it doesn't work like what i want.. How can i set it to do that automatically after the set resolution ?

Thanks for help a lot!

**[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmYmww)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var width = $(window).outerWidth();
  if (width <= '860') {
    $('[id=title]').each(function() {
        var title = $(this).text();
        if (title.length > 90) {
        title = title.substr(0, 90) + '...';    
        }
        $(this).text(title);
     });
  } else {
    $('[id=title]').each(function() {
        var title = $(this).text();
        if (title.length > 42) {
        title = title.substr(0, 42) + '...';    
        }
        $(this).text(title);
     });
  }
});
```

```html
<h4 id="title">The Great Big Headline That Attracts User Eyeballs</h4>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to listen to the resize event on the window object: `$(window).on('resize', function(){`

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
 var width = $(window).outerWidth();
  if (width <= '860') {
    $('[id=title]').each(function() {
        var title = $(this).text();
        if (title.length > 90) {
         title = title.substr(0, 90) + '...';     
        }
        $(this).text(title);
     });
  } else {
    $('[id=title]').each(function() {
       var title = $(this).text();
        if (title.length > 42) {
         title = title.substr(0, 42) + '...';    
        }
        $(this).text(title);
     });
   }
});
```

However, when I look at your function I believe you should look into using CSS3 instead: something like this:

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 85%;
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: Its works better when i resize the page under 860px its works but when i resize it back above 860px it stay like under 860px ...

Comment: I believe once the title has been cut off, you can't reverse this, since you're not storing the initial value anywhere

Comment: See addition with CSS in initial answer